# Create a table both in-memory and transaction-safe in MySQL

Tags: mysql, memory, innodb

I know I should use `engine=MEMORY` to make the table in memory and `engine=INNODB` to make the table transaction safe. However, how can I achieve both objectives? I tried `engine=MEMORY, INNODB`, but I failed. My purpose is to access tables fast and allow multiple threads to change contents of tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't stated your goals above. I guess you're looking for good performance, and you also seem to want the table to be transactional. Your only option really is InnoDB. As long as you have configured InnoDB to use enough memory to hold your entire table (with `innodb_buffer_pool_size`), and there is not excessive pressure from other InnoDB tables on the same server, the data will remain in memory. If you're concerned about write performance (and again barring other uses of the same system) you can reduce durability to drastically increase write performance by setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0` and disabling binary logging.

Using any sort of triggers with temporary tables will be a mess to maintain, and won't give you any benefits of transactionality on the temporary tables.

Comment: Hi jeremycole, I add my purpose just now. Yes, it is quite similar to what you say. I will try your method . Thank you very much. By the way, I find [mysql cluster](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster.html). It seems it can achieve both my objectives.

Comment: What are your performance goals? You haven't stated any reason that InnoDB itself would not work. InnoDB is very "fast".

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a way to create the table with 2 (or more) engines, that is not possible with mysql.

However, I will guess that you want to use memory because you don't think innodb will be fast enough for your need. I think innodb is pretty fast and will be probably enough, but if you really need it, I think you should try creating 2 tables:

table1 memory <-- here is where you will make all the SELECTs

table2 innodb <-- here you will make the UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, etc and add a TRIGGER so when this one is updated, the table1 gets the same modification.

Comment: Hi Mickle, thank you for giving me the idea. My data set is too big, so I cannot use your idea.

Answer (score 0):

as i know the there are two ways

**1st way**

create a temp table as ( these are stored in memory with a small diff they will get deleted as the session is logged out )

**create temporary table** sample(id **int**) **engine**=Innodb;

**2nd way**

you have to create two tables one with memory engine and other with innodb or bdb

first insert all the data into your innodb table and then trigger the data to be copied into memory table

and if you want to empty the data in the innodb table you can do it with same trigger

you can achieve this using events also

Comment: Hi vidyadhar, thank you for your ideas. Mysql documentation says temporary table may be moved to disks when it becomes too large, so I cannot use this way.

Comment: yes right but you have to truncate the table frequentltly or increase memory parameters like max heap tables,etc